# How to dynamically change the menu items in Notepad++ plugin

Tags: c#, winforms, notepad++

I'm developing a plugin for Notepad++ in C# where I need to dynamically change the label of menu items (e.g. from "Login" to "Logout").

For this task I use the Win32 APIs, namely the method

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool SetMenuItemInfo(IntPtr hMenu, int uItem, bool fByPosition, MENUITEMINFO lpmii);
```

Sometimes the menu is not updated even if no error arise in the calls to this method.

Do I need to invoke any Notepad++ command to force a refresh of the menu?

Thank you very much!

Best

cghersi

Comment: Nowhere it is mentioned on the doc to use SetMenuItemInfo : http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Plugin_Development#Menu_initialisation and http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Plugin_Development_Quick_Start_Guide See the example plugin project.

Comment: @Aybe you're right, but after asking to the Notepad++ forum I received this hint: http://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/discussion/482781/thread/c9d278ab/